# Summarize difference between two data frame

Tags: r, dplyr

I have two different Dataset called Aug and Sept

see a sample of the dataset below.
September

| Sept |
| --- |
| 9887 |
| 9888 |
| 9889 |
| 9890 |
| 9891 |
| 9892 |
| 9893 |
| 9894 |
| 9895 |
| 9896 |
| 9897 |
| 9898 |
| 9899 |
| 9900 |

and August

| Augu |
| --- |
| 9887 |
| 9888 |
| 9889 |
| 9890 |
| 9891 |
| 3223 |
| 3223 |
| 3223 |
| 3223 |
| 3223 |
| 3223 |
| 6563 |
| 6563 |
| 6563 |
| 6563 |
| 6563 |

What I want is to calculate the count and percentage of numbers in Aug that's not in Sept,
2. calculate new numbers in Sept that is not in Aug and the numbers in Aug and Sep in count and percentage

Please remember that these are two diff data frames.
any R package is welcome but I will prefer tidyverse or dplyr package

Thank you

Comment: Can you please include the output of `dput(Aug)` and `dput(Sept)` in the text of your question? That will make it easier to load the data in the same format you have it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
# Count of numbers in August but not in September
nrow(anti_join(df1, df2, c('Augu' = 'Sept')))
[1] 11

# Count of numbers in September not in August
nrow(anti_join(df2, df1, c('Sept' = 'Augu')))
[1] 9

# Count of numbers in both August and September
nrow(inner_join(df2, df1, c('Sept' = 'Augu')))
[1] 5
```

Data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Augu = c(9887L, 9888L, 9889L, 9890L, 9891L, 3223L, 
3223L, 3223L, 3223L, 3223L, 3223L, 6563L, 6563L, 6563L, 6563L, 
6563L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -16L))

df2 <- structure(list(Sept = 9887:9900), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-14L))
```